# Integrating grails and MongoDB? need any tutorial

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm new to Mongodb and grails. Does any one has a good link like .pdf, video tutorial for integrating and developing using Mongodb and grails? I tried to search the web but there are no good link or sites for beginners. 
Thanks!

Comment: I think that this question suits better in the grails user list.

Comment: If you're new to Grails, that's a good place to start. I'd recommend the book, The Definitive Guide to Grails. While learning Grails, you will learn Gorm which is Grails' de facto ORM. The MongoDB Gorm plugin is what you'll want to use. As for a quick start tutorial... For the most part, what you learn about Gorm from most tutorials will apply to SQL and NoSQL databases. The point of any ORM is that the underlying data storage mechanism is abstracted from the business concerns of your software. I've used Gorm for SQL and Mongo. It is really powerful and useful for both.

Comment: You can try with Mongodb plugin .
Check out here : http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tutorials out there, but these seem decent:

- http://blog.mongodb.org/post/18510469058/grails-in-the-land-of-mongodb
- http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2013/05/28/understanding-mongodb-object-modeling-in-grails-and-gorm/